# Is it possible to disable text chat on battlefront 2 (classic 2005)

Tags: star-wars-battlefront-2

The question pretty much says it.  Is it possible to disable text chat, through settings, or maybe there's a cheat I can use that would be allowed on online servers?  I haven't seen anything in the settings, but I could be missing it.

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing H to hide the chat. If its the same as Battlefield pressing H toggles the chat between always show, only when active and hidden.
Otherwise there is no such option.

Comment: I don't think this worked, but I guess I'd rather give someone the reputation than have no one have it.  Enjoy.  If you'd wrather earn the reputation yourself, than just use it as a bounty for a question u ask, or award it to a good answer to another question.  (anyone who doesn't like this, fight the stupid bounty system, not me or darkphoenix  =)

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: no problem,  thnx for answering. =)